# Unable to get coordinates from bing map REST api

Tags: rest, bing-maps, bing-api

We have a list of address, And trying to get coordinates of them using server side script.

Due to limitation of google map api(2500 query per 24 hour), We move to bing map REST api.

But when we are calling API its not giving the coordinates, While google map api returning the correct coordinates.
Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here is the sample call

```
 http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=A+Beka+Acadamdy,2303+Maravilla,Lompoc,CA,93436,&incl=queryParse&key=MY_API_KEY
```

if I replace everything with %20 in address then still its not returning data

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=A%20Beka%20Acadamdy%202303%20Maravilla%20Lompoc%20CA%2093436&incl=queryParse&key=MY_API_KEY
```

Another URL is

```
 http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=103+Black+Men+of+the+Bay+Area+Community,3403+Malcolm+Avenue,Oakland,CA,94607-1407,&incl=queryParse&key=MY_API_KEY
```

We also tried with this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817004.aspx#sectionToggle6

But sometimes we don't know the country, That's why its not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to change. First, drop the name of the location, you only need the street address.

So geocoding "2303 Maravilla, Lompoc, CA, 93436" will work.

Secondly, it looks like you are escaping the query value rather than encoding it. Escaping isn't as good as encoding and will result in some queries failing all together. For example if a query had "first & Main" in it, escaping it would not escape the ampersand which would make everything after it a new URL parameter which would likely either cause an error or mean your query is just for "first". By encoding it the ampersand would be changed to %26. This is documented in the best practices here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx

By encoding your query parameter your address will look like this:

```
"2303%20Maravilla,%20Lompoc,%20CA,%2093436"
```